# Custom value change listener in android?

Tags: android, listener

Need your help or advice. 
The aim is to get continuous updates from method android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthWcdma.getDbm() (Get the mobile network signal strength as dBm) and make update of correspondent text view when the value provided by the method changes.

The first approach of the solution is to request for value in *do-while* cycle with predefined time interval, like 1 second, check the difference between common and previous values and make decision of textView update.

So the question is maybe there is some other better way to do this, like using kind of system listener etc?

BR,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a PhoneStateListener to your TelephonyManager using the proper method listen(). You need to pass a sub class of PhoneStateListener and the event you want to get. For example you can listen for PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO; in this case the method onCellInfoChanged (List cellInfo) of your PhoneStateListener is called, providing you the info you need, avoiding a loop.

Comment: Thanks, you helped much! That's what I've needed.